# Run SparkSQL query for each line in PySpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that contains parameters of a SQL query I need to run. I ultimately need the results of all of these SQL queries to be stored in a separate dataframe. Currently, I am mapping over each row of my parameter dataframe, then using a custom function to create the SQL query that needs run, like so:

```
# Example df
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("contract", 123), 
        ("customer", 223),
    ],
    ["id_type", "ids"] 
)
df.show()

+--------+----+
| id_type| ids|
+--------+----+
|contract| 123|
|customer| 223|
+--------+----+

________________________________________________________________________________________

# Create custom function that will write a sql query
def query_writer(id_type, ids):
    qry = f'''
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE {id_type}_id = '{ids}'
    '''
    return sqlContext.sql(qry) # I also tried saving the results as a dictionary and outputting that

# Apply this function to each row of the dataframe    
rdd1 = df.rdd.map(lambda x:(x[0], x[1], query_writer(x[0], x[1])))
qry = rdd1.take(1)
```

But, I get this error:

```
Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. 
SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. 
For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Is there any way to run a SQL query for each row of a dataframe in PySpark?

I happen to know that the query will always return 4 rows, if that is helpful.

Comment: Did you tried broadcasting the `sqlContext` variable before executing your custom function?

Comment: I think that is where the problem is, I can't. `SparkContext can only be used on the driver`, I just wasn't sure if there is another way to run sql mapped across multiple rows.

Comment: the `table` refers to another dataframe right?

Comment: ^ yes, the query is actually quite long, I shortened it here to make it easier to explain.